# Wreath products of groups in Mathematica?

Tags: group-theory

Looking online, I found [this](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/580/) external package that can compute e.g. the [`CycleIndexPolynomial`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CycleIndexPolynomial.html) of wreath products of symmetry groups. Considering that this package is 18 years old, I am wondering if this functionality has been integrated into Mathematica yet?
Trying to search for "wreath product of groups" in the documentation, I did not find anything. Is the above external package still the only option to calculate [`CycleIndexPolynomial`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CycleIndexPolynomial.html) of wreath products of symmetry groups in Mathematica?